# How to merge, create tags and put an ascending order the feeds of more RSS Feed links like on Yahoo Pipes?

Tags: java, android, rss, feed, yahoo-pipes

I need to take the feeds of more `RSS Feed` urls that I have to aggregate and show the news in descending order.

Some links don't have an `xml` tag for `<category>` so I need to create one: I have to know where feeds come from so that I can categorize them.

This is what I'm trying to achieve: ( for **Source n** I mean the category)

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I used to use `Yahoo!Pipes` to make all these changes.

My attempt was to create a `CustomListView` for each url and then execute the `AsyncTasks` all at once but that is not working correctly - the feeds are not displayed in ascending order.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
    private RSSFeed myRssFeed = null;
    String[] urlFeed = {"url1", "url2"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        for (int i = 0; i < urlFeed.length; i++) {
            News news = new News(i);
            news.execute();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        for (int i = 0; i < urlFeed.length; i++) {
            News news = new News(i);
            news.execute();
        }
    }

    private class News extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void> {
        protected int number;
        public News(int urlNumber) {
            number = urlNumber;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Object... arg0) {

            String data = "";
            InputStream iStream;

            try{
                URL url = new URL(urlFeed[number]);

                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Connecting to url
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Reading data from url
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

                StringBuilder sbf  = new StringBuilder();

                String line;
                while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                    sbf.append(line);
                }

                data = sbf.toString();

                br.close();

                SAXParserFactory mySAXParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser mySAXParser = mySAXParserFactory.newSAXParser();
                XMLReader myXMLReader = mySAXParser.getXMLReader();
                RSSHandler myRSSHandler = new RSSHandler();
                myXMLReader.setContentHandler(myRSSHandler);
                InputSource myInputSource = new InputSource(url.openStream());
                myXMLReader.parse(myInputSource);

                myRssFeed = myRSSHandler.getFeed();

            } catch (ParserConfigurationException | IOException | SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (myRssFeed != null) {

                NestedListView list = (NestedListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
                list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                CustomList adapter = new CustomList(MainActivity.this, myRssFeed.getList());
                adapter.addAll();
                list.setAdapter(adapter);

            } else
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**RSSFeed**

```
public class RSSFeed {
    private String title = null;
    private String description = null;
    private String link = null;
    private String pubdate = null;
    private String image = null;
    private String enclosure = null;
    private String author = null;
    private List<RSSItem> itemList;

    RSSFeed(){
        itemList = new Vector<RSSItem>(0);
    }

    void addItem(RSSItem item){
        itemList.add(item);
    }
    RSSItem getItem(int location){
        return itemList.get(location);
    }
    List<RSSItem> getList(){
        return itemList;
    }

}
```

**RSSItem**

```
public class RSSItem {

    private String title = null;
    private String description = null;
    private String link = null;
    private String pubdate = null;
    private String image = null;
    private String enclosure = null;
    private String author = null;
}
```

**CustomList**

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> {

    private static Activity context = null;
    private final List<RSSItem> web;

    public CustomList(Activity context, List<RSSItem> web) {
        super(context, R.layout.new_listview, web);
        CustomList.context = context;
        this.web = web;
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        @SuppressLint({"ViewHolder", "InflateParams"}) final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_listview, null, true);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            Picasso.with(context).load(web.get(position).getImage()).into(imageView);

        TextView textView = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(web.get(position).getTitle()));

        TextView textView1 = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        textView1.setText(web.get(position).getDescription());

        TextView textView2 = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.pubdate);
        textView2.setText(pubdate);

        return rowView;

    }

}
```

**RSSHandler**

```
public class RSSHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    final int state_unknown = 0;
    final int state_title = 1;
    final int state_description = 2;
    final int state_link = 3;
    final int state_pubdate = 4;
    final int state_enclosure = 6;
    final int state_image = 5;
    final int state_author = 7;
    int currentState = state_unknown;
    String url;

    RSSFeed feed;
    RSSItem item;

    boolean itemFound = false;

    RSSHandler(){
    }

    RSSFeed getFeed(){
        return feed;
    }

    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        feed = new RSSFeed();
        item = new RSSItem();

    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                         Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
            itemFound = true;
            item = new RSSItem();
            currentState = state_unknown;
        }
        else if (localName.equals("enclosure")) {
            url = attributes.getValue("url");
            currentState = state_image;
        }
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title")){
            currentState = state_title;
        }
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("description")){
            currentState = state_description;
        }
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("link")){
            currentState = state_link;
        }
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("pubdate")){
            currentState = state_pubdate;
        }
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("author")){
            currentState = state_author;
        }
        else{
            currentState = state_unknown;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
            feed.addItem(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String strCharacters = new String(ch,start,length);

        if (itemFound){
            // "item" tag found, it's item's parameter
            switch(currentState){
                case state_enclosure:
                    item.setEnclosure(strCharacters);
                    break;
                case state_title:
                    item.setTitle(strCharacters);
                    break;
                case state_image:
                    item.setImage(url);
                    break;
                case state_description:
                    item.setDescription(strCharacters);
                    break;
                case state_link:
                    item.setLink(strCharacters);
                    break;
                case state_pubdate:
                    item.setPubdate(strCharacters);
                    break;
                case state_author:
                    item.setAuthor(strCharacters);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        else{
            // not "item" tag found, it's feed's parameter
            switch(currentState){
                case state_enclosure:
                    feed.setEnclosure(strCharacters);
                    break;
                case state_title:
                    feed.setTitle(strCharacters);
                    break;
                case state_image:
                    feed.setImage(url);
                    break;
                case state_description:
                    feed.setDescription(strCharacters);
                    break;
                case state_link:
                    feed.setLink(strCharacters);
                    break;
                case state_pubdate:
                    feed.setPubdate(strCharacters);
                    break;
                case state_author:
                    feed.setAuthor(strCharacters);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        currentState = state_unknown;
    }
```

Comment: I should have explained it better: as far as my knowledge is I can't do it programmatically. Anyways my feed are written in xml.

Comment: Where exactly do you have problems? Why can't you simply have one list to append all the data and then start doing the requests. As those requests finish, aggregate the newly received data with the old one and also sort it in the process.

Comment: I already tried to use a list and get the feed from the urls but I can't show the category of the feed as I have to create a tag for each url

Comment: @NickCardoso for example this _http://iltirreno.gelocal.it/rss/cmlink/rss-il-tirreno-grosseto-cronaca-1.10108886_ and this _http://iltirreno.gelocal.it/rss/cmlink/rss-il-tirreno-grosseto-sport-1.10108903_ . They are from 2 different categories

Comment: @NickCardoso Strangely for me the second link works. Anyway those where two examples of links. I added a screenshot

Comment: Ok, thats a useful image. I think what I'm confused by is "display their category adding tags like I could do on Yahoo Pipes", is that just the part where you show the source nuber in the image?

Comment: Yes that is what I meant

Comment: Ok, Post the code you had before where you got the feeds but the tags and orderign were wrong, and I'll show you how it can be fixed

Comment: @NickCardoso check the edit

Comment: I added all the classes

Comment: Thanks for the bounty @Rick, Did you figure this out and have an answer to post? It's ok to post your own answer if the other doesn't help you enough that you want to accept it, but it's good to accept an answer so other people with the same problem find it now the question has been upvoted

Answer (score 2):

The solution requires more than one change. The first thing you need to do is make each News task that finishes adds its data to the one big list. That list can then be sorted which requires a `Comparator`.

You also need a list of the names to show in the placeholder youve called `Source n` in your image and lastly,  so that you can compare them, you need to parse the dates as actual dates.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    private List<RSSItem> totalRssFeed = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] urlFeed = {"MyURL", "MyUrl2", "MyUrl3"};
    String[] names = {"Name", "Name2", "Name3"} 
    private CustomList adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomList(MainActivity.this);
        list.setAdapter( adapter );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // do this here and you dont need to repeat it in refresh and create
        for (int i = 0; i < urlFeed.length; i++) {
            News news = new News(i);
            news.execute();
        }
    }

    public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> {

        ...

        public CustomList(Activity context) { //dont start with default data
            super(context, R.layout.new_listview, null);
        }

        ...

    }

    private class News extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void> {

        protected int number;

        public News(int urlNumber) {
            number = urlNumber;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
            try {

                //no need to do the input stuff you were doing before here?
                URL url = new URL(urlFeed[number]);
                SAXParserFactory mySAXParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser mySAXParser = mySAXParserFactory.newSAXParser();
                XMLReader myXMLReader = mySAXParser.getXMLReader();
                RSSHandler myRSSHandler = new RSSHandler(names[number]);
                myXMLReader.setContentHandler(myRSSHandler);
                InputSource myInputSource = new InputSource(url.openStream());
                myXMLReader.parse(myInputSource);
                totalRssFeed.addAll(myRSSHandler.getFeed());
                Collections.sort(totalRssFeed);

            } catch (ParserConfigurationException | IOException | SAXException e) { /* stuff */ }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            adapter.clear();
            adapter.addAll(totalRssFeed);
        }

    }

    public class RSSItem implements Comparable<RSSItem> {

        public String tag;
        public Date pubdate; //just public so i didnt need setters in this example

        public RSSItem(String defaultTagToUse) {
            //You should set the default to whatever you want displayed
            //when the tag for <category> is missing, and just update it normally otherwise
            tag = defaultTagToUse;
        }

        void setPubDate(Date date) {
            pubdate = date;
        }

        ...

        @Override
        public int compareTo(@NonNull RSSItem another) {
            int res;
            if (pubdate == null) {
                if (another.pubdate == null) {
                    res = 0;
                } else {
                    res = -1;
                }
            } else {
                if (another.pubdate == null || pubdate.getTime() > another.pubdate.getTime()) {
                    res = 1;
                } else {
                    res = -1;
                }
            }
            return res;
        }

    }

    public class RSSHandler extends DefaultHandler {

        ...
        List<RSSItem> feed;
        RSSItem item;
        String mName;

        public RssHandler(String name) {
            mName = name;
        } 

        List<RSSItem> getFeed() {
            return feed;
        }

        @Override
        public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
            feed = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
            if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                itemFound = true;
                item = new RSSItem( name ); 
                currentState = state_unknown;
            } else ...
        }

        @Override
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
            if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                feed.add(item);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
            ...
            case state_pubdate:
                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"); //make sure you match the format from your XML
                item.setPubdate( formatter.parse(stringCharacters) );
            break;
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

All the `...`'s jsut mean leave everything as it was in those places

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the part where I add more Urls

Comment: I have to get the feed of different urls not just one, but in you code I don't see where I add other urls

Comment: Ok now I got it but how does it work for the name of the sources? How I display the different sources?

Comment: Yes but you said that I should set the default for whatever I want displayed when the tag category is missing but the tag category is always missing in those urls

Comment: Could you please make me just another little example so that I get it completely?

Comment: Yes but I do not understand how I access the urls separately and name them. Do I have to create more RSSHandlers, one for each url? And then how would I get their name?

Comment: I did write my code to better fit my needs, I just didn't understand what you did cause I'm still learning and I need very detailed explainations to understand.
The last question, then I'll reward you the bounty, is how I display the name of the sources in the TextView

Comment: Ah I just looked at your answer and your adapter. In getview you'll need to get the right item so `whicheverTextView.setText(web.get(position).getTag()) `

Comment: Anyway I tried your code but the feed are not in ascending order, there are first the feeds from the first url, than the second and the third. When I tried to display the pubDate with setText the result was 0

Comment: If you read the comment in my code i said you need to make sure youre using the right format. You need to print out the date string you get back from your feed and work it out

Comment: Yes you're right, It was my fault I didn't mention I already did that change before I edited again the question, I set like you _EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z_. Anyway I'll give you the bounty and sorry for disturbing